# Establishing to-many relationships between NSManagedObjects created in a NSBatchInsertRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In my sample app, a `CDStory` has a to-one relationship `source` that maps *one* `CDStory` to *one* `CDNewsSource`.

Also, a `CDNewsSource` has a to-many relationship `story` that maps *one* `CDNewsSource` to *one or more* `CDStory` instances.

Naturally, the inverse of `source` is `story`.

When I create a `CDStory` instance, I would like to immediately set the `CDNewsSource` to which it should map. However, when I do this in a batch insert request, I get an error about different contexts, even though it looks like the context I'm adding the `CDNewsSource` to should match the the context of the `CDStory`.*

#### Code

```
let context = container.newBackgroundContext()
context.performAndWait { /* Thread 3: "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'source' between objects in different contexts... */
    let total = items.count
    var i = 0
    let batchInsert = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: CDStory.entity(), managedObjectHandler: { managedObject in
        guard i < total else { return true }
        defer { i += 1 }
        let story = managedObject as! CDStory
        let item = items[i]
        story.title = item.title
        let source = CDNewsSource(context: context)
        managedStoryObject.source = source /* Establishing relationship here. */
        return false
    })
    try! context.execute(batchInsert)
}
```

*From the error log, I do see that the context of execution is an `NSSQLBatchInsertRequestContext`, which is probably different than the background context used in the `managedObjectHandler` of the `NSBatchInsertRequest`. It's not clear how that could be since I am specifying the context when I execute and create the batch insert request.

#### Complete error log

```
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request
<NSSQLBatchInsertRequestContext: 0x6000014fe8e0> , Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'source' between objects in different contexts
  (source = <CDStory: 0x6000013c0ff0> (entity: CDStory; id: 0x600003098e00 <x-coredata:///CDStory/tAEF068C8-35C0-4287-8F13-84D6B5B35A6D2>; data: {
      title = "Example Story Title";
      source = nil;
  }) , destination = <CDNewsSource: 0x6000013c37a0> (entity: CDNewsSource; id: 0x600003099100 <x-coredata:///CDNewsSource/tAEF068C8-35C0-4287-8F13-84D6B5B35A6D3>; data: {
      name = nil;
      story =     (
      );
  }))
```

Comment: Do you really want to create a new source here?  Shouldn't you be querying for an existing source and only creating a new source if a matching existing source can't be found? You can use `story.managedObjectContext` rather than your `context` to operate in the same context as the batch operation.

Comment: Even though the `story` is a valid `NSManagedObject` in the closure, `story.managedObjectContext` is `nil`. Is that really how you get the batch insert's context?

Comment: And yes, I want to get an existing source but those are saved in the container's `viewContext`, so I haven't yet figured out how to fetch an object. I think I'll cache the NSManagedObjectID, though it seems unstable

Comment: The first question I would ask is do you really need to use a batch insert?  Don't pre-optimise.  Just use a simple loop over your data, inserting each entity as you go and `saveContext` when you are done.  Definitely don't cache managed object ids.  You should be able to access the batch insert context as I said and perform your query against that.  It is a child context

Comment: The batch insert is the very point of this, I'm trying to gain a better understanding of batch operations.

Comment: In the `managedObjectHandler` I can get things to work with this snippet, but like you said I shouldn't cache the IDs and seems strange to have to add `story` to the bg context:
    `context.insert(story) // seems bad!`;
    `story.source = context.object(with: sourceManagedObjectID) as? CDNewsSource`

Comment: (Also, I suspect the [batch insert](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest) really doesn't add objects to any context as the benefit comes from directly writing to a store, no in-memory/context modifications.)

Comment: It has to be operating on a context - You can see from your error log in your question.  The question is can you perform queries against an instance of `NSSQLBatchInsertRequestContext`?  Have you already tried without using the batch insert?  Is performance that bad? unless you are inserting tens of thousands of stories I would be suprised if you saw any real benefit

Comment: It's purely instructional so yes tens of thousands of cells in a collection view. I've had great result with batch processing without Core Data Relationships, I guess I will have to look into that

Answer (score 1):

Buried in the Apple docs archive, I've found my answer:

> A batch update cannot be used to alter relationships, delete entities, or create new entities.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchUpdates/BatchUpdates.html

Comment: That source is actually about NSBatchUpdateRequest, not NSBatchInsertRequest.  Note that it says it cannot delete entities, but certainly NSBatchDeleteRequest can delete entities.  Nevertheless, it is plausible given that the batch requests operate directly on the persistent store that none of them are able to alter relationships.